# How to make two return in one controller on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, redirect, controller, return

I'm try make two return in one controller, after form submit open new tab for download and back to index for origin page.

my controller

```
 $type_leaves = TypeLeave::find($type_leaves_id);
    $type_leaves_all= TypeLeave::all();
    $employee = Employee::find($employee_id);
    $leavesEmployee = new Leaves;

    $viewLeaves = Leaves::find($leaves);
    $date=date('Y-m-d');


      $pdf = PDF::loadView('leaves.coverLetter', compact('type_leaves','employee', 'viewLeaves','type_leaves_all','leavesEmployee','date'));
        $pdf->setPaper('legal','potrait');
        return $pdf->download('letter-cover.pdf');

        return redirect()->route('leaves.view',$employee_id)->with(['success' => 'Data Cuti Pegawai Berhasil Di Proses']);
```

Comment: Just don't return the first. It should still download without needing to open a new page for the download.  Or make the download happen via ajax before the page submits like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate through javascript, do a `window.open('your_url', "_blank");` your controller will return only one route. remove `return $pdf->download('letter-cover.pdf');`

This 'your_url` will be a new route, and for this controller do

`$pdf = PDF::loadView('leaves.coverLetter', compact('type_leaves','employee', 'viewLeaves','type_leaves_all','leavesEmployee','date'));
        $pdf->setPaper('legal','potrait');
        return $pdf->download('letter-cover.pdf');`

Comment: What if in my form be founf validation form request, if there is an empty field stay view message error without window open ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that via javascript as well. Simply disable the button until the validation succeeds. or in your route `leaves.view` you can implement javascript here, with `window.onload = function() {
  yourDownloadFunction();
};` make sure to place this JS script in top of your `leaves.view`